# Get full image in Typo3

Tags: typo3

is there any way to get the full/unprocessed image from the url of a proccessed one?

For example: Is it possible to get the url of the original image from this url?
`https://www.assmann.de/fileadmin/_processed_/1/a/csm_Quality_Office_03_528c1c1990.jpg`
I don't have any access to the backend - just as a visitor.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't get the URL to the unprocessed image, if the URL cannot be found anywhere in the HTML (e.g. if an image is rendered with different source-tags and the largest is possibly without image processing) if you are only a visitor.